# How can I concat a variable with table name in Postgresql Function?

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.3

> This portion is inside a function in Postgresql.

```sql
v_merchant_wallet:='018xxxxxxxxxx'
    
bank:='_xyz'

select
  a.id
into v_account_id
from
  schemma.accounts'''||bank||''' a
where
  a.username = v_merchant_wallet;
```

- In above portion `bank` name is dynamically passed through a function. then the bank will save the value inside it.

I tried differently.  But could not solve this .

Comment: Search for dynamic SQL. Or revise your schema. You possibly should only have one table for the accounts and a column in it designating the bank it belongs to. (Tables in relational databases aren't "online" spreadsheets.)

Comment: Without the real code it's difficult to help you, but you should at least use quote_ident() to avoid SQL injection. A better schema sounds even better and doesn't have the problem you're already facing.

Comment: We have 4 tables for accounts.... 4 tables for 4 different bank..... This is private financial organization in our country.....

Comment: @Md.ImrulHasan: Yes, that's what I thought of. And that's wrong. As I already wrote, use one table for all accounts and a column in that table where an identifier referencing the bank is stored per account.